# Can't Play From Save Playlist File (.xml)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I need your help. I've made this code for loading from save playlist file (.xml), load file works, but it can't play.

When playing it, there's an error appear from `listbox1`.

I think `SelectedIndex` already exists in `filePaths`, but I don't know how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 1)
       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = filePaths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
}
```

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxvFZ.png)

Comment: What error are you getting now? By using the debugger you can easily check if `SelectedIndex` exists in `filePaths`.

Comment: The error is "Nullreferenceexception was unhandled" at axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = filePaths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a `NullReferenceException was unhandled` error the problem might be that `SelectedIndex` is `null`. This happens when no item was selected in your`listBox1`

Try checking that before attempting to use it:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 1 && listBox1.SelectedIndex != null)
       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = filePaths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But the problem is still the same at "axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = filePaths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];" the yellow highline show on this code with a warning message "NullReferenceException was unhandled"

Comment: Try debugging to see which one is null. It could be that `axWindowsMediaPlayer1` or `filePaths` haven't been initialized.

Comment: It's at filePaths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];

Comment: In visual studio you can see exactly which values each one has, here it explains how to do this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/15/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/ just look for which one is null

Comment: I've added a picture to description my problem. I hope it will help you to understand about this problem. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxvFZ.png

Comment: On the bottom of your picture there is a grid that shows the value of `AwsMediaPlayer1`. If you check there you should be able to see the value of the other things (`filePaths`, `listBox1`, etc.). Otherwise you will need to set a breakpoint in the line and debug to see the values before the error occurs.

Comment: There's a lot of occurs on the bottom. So tired, may be I'll give up. Thank you so much for your time and for your help, moondaisy. You're awesome! :D

Comment: Don't! It's a really easy error to fix, you just need to pinpoint what is null. Check if the "view details" link in the error you are getting doesn't give you more info on what is null. But debugging is going to be your best friend, so it's better to start learning with this simple errors

Comment: Thank you for your advice, moondaisy. I'll try again. Sorry I'm still so new for Visual Studio. :(